# Unable to use jquery to POST data using Web api

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, api

I am not able even to alert a message using jQuery, what is wrong with my code?
When I used post man, I was able to add to a database.

I want to use the post methode to be able to post the data to the data base

View:

```
@model API.Models.Customers


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>New Form</h2>

<div id="container">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group" id="Name">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        <br />
        <p id="demo"></p>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary js-Add">Save</button>
    </form>
    </div>



    @section scripts {

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            
            $("#container .js-Add").on("click", function () {
                var button = $(this);
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to ADD this customer?")) {
                    var input = $("Name").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/api/Customer/CreateCustomer",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: input,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert('HELLO' + response.Name);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

API CONTROLLER:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateCustomer(Customers CustomerDTO)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
      
        _context.Customerss.Add(CustomerDTO);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Created(new Uri(Request.RequestUri + "/" + CustomerDTO.Id), CustomerDTO);

    }
```

MVC CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult New(Customers customers)
    {
       
        return View(customers);
    }
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: you need to cancel the form submitting.

Comment: console.log response

Answer (score 0):

Please change your div **id** property value to something else rather than **Name**. for instance change it to `<div class="form-group" id="NameGroup">` then you can change your JS code to something like this:

```
$(function () {
            $("#container .js-Add").click(function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to ADD this customer?")) {

                    let personName = $("#Name").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/home/PostPerson",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: { Name: personName },
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert('HELLO' + response.Name);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Don't forget to change your posted object based on your object.

Answer (score 0):

Your header/content-type must be match the data which your posting. So if you convert your data to JSON it should be work. you can use `JSON.stringify(your data)`